# How to check if a tweet is a novel tweet?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

After collecting status objects using tweepy, I need to check whether the tweet is a novel or  retweet/reply/quote. I know how to check quote and retweet. I used

> tweet.in_reply_to_status_id == None and 
>     tweet.in_reply_to_user_id == None

but for some tweets which are actually replies, this method does not work ([such as this](https://twitter.com/docweiser01/status/746585941423292416)). This is strange that both fields are `None` but it is actually a reply. Is there any other field in the status object or any other api method to verify this?

Does checking if the text starts with mentioning some user guaranteed to work?

EDIT: I also tried with Twarc, but it return same result.

EDIT2: I wonder if this is a problem with the public API, since when twitter shows that tweet, it also shows the original tweet which would not be possible if it did not know that it is a reply to some other tweet.

Comment: Does the tweet you linked above still contain the @<username> portion or is that stripped as part of the new Twitter reply standards?

Comment: @mattdonders, it still has @<username>, but other tweets that simply mentions some user also start this way.